# How to delete google calendar using calendar name in google API?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I have a two Calendar(1.squad 2.genius). i want to delete the second one (genius) with out using calendar id.is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/delete) or [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/delete) you'll absolutely need the calendar id to perform the delete request.
I suggest that you implement a function that will get all calendars and get the id of the one you want to delete.
Also, when you create a calendar, the standard return of your request return the calendarId. It might be intresting to persist it somewhere !